# Multivariate Integral Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f, g: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$.  Can I show that there is always a set $S \subseteq [0,1]^2 $ such that
$$
\int_{(x_1, x_2) \in[0,1]^2} f(x_1, x_2) x_1 + g(x_1, x_2) x_2\ d x_1\ d x_2 =
\int_{(x_1, x_2) \in S} ( f(x_1, x_2) + g(x_1, x_2) )\ d x_1\ d x_2\, ?
$$
I am also interested in assuming more about $f, g$ in order for the above to be true, integrability or even continuity are definitely ok.

For one-dimensional functions, I can do it using the Fubini theorem.
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be any integrable function.
We have that
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) x d x =
\int_0^1 f(x) \int_0^x d t\ dx =
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x) \mathbb{1}\{x < t\} dx \ dt
= \int_0^1 r(t) dt,
$$
where $r(t) = \int_0^1 f(x) \mathbb{1}\{x < t\} d x$.  By the mean value theorem for integrals
we obtain that there exists some $t_0$ such that
$\int_0^1 r(t) = r(t_0)$.  This means that there exists some $t_0$ such that
$\int_0^1 f(x) x d x = \int_0^{t_0} f(x) d x$.  I cannot generalize this argument to the two dimensional case above.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be true in general.  Take $f(x_1, x_2) = -x_1$ and $g(x_1, x_2) = x_1$.  Then $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 -x_1^2 + x_1 x_2\ d x_1 d x_2 = -1/3 + 1/4.$$ However, for every set $S$ it holds $$\int_S (f + g) d x_1 d x_2 = 0.$$